# I am trying to close the window after executing some code but the window is not closing, tried window.close(); and close(); still not working

Tags: javascript

//close window section is the problem, it just won't close the current tab. I am jus running some code to download a file and then I require the tab to close automatically as if nothing happened to make the UX better. But window.close(); and close(); is not working. Tried a lot of stuff found on Internet still not working. What's wrong with my code?

```js
var url_string = window.location; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var file = url.searchParams.get("file");
var dFile = file;

function onLoad() {
  if (dFile !== null) {
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

    // Download
    hiddenElement.href = `${dFile}`;
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = `${dFile}`;
    hiddenElement.click();

    //Close Window
    var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
    win.close();
  } else {

  }
}

//Set The value of the File being Downloaded
if (dFile !== null) {
  var SetFile = document.getElementById('xdFile')
  SetFile.innerHTML = "Downloading" + " " + dFile + " " + "now"
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an empty window just to close it immediately?

Comment: The `window.open()` function opens a new window, it doesn't get the window that was created from clicking on the hidden anchor.

Comment: I am not really trying to do that, I just want to close the current window, I don't want to open any new tabs. but for some reason window.close() does not work

Comment: JS can only close a window that it opened.

Comment: discord somehow closes the window without issues